# Java - Null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am creating a simple video game and I have been trying to add some basic collision detection. I am doing this out of a entityCollision.class that I have created. The collision detection uses rectangles that are placed outside of the charater of AI. I am trying to create these rectangles by doing this:

```
Movement Movement;
AIMovement AIMovement;

Rectangle player = new Rectangle(Movement.x + 4, Movement.y, 56, 64);
Rectangle robot1 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[0] + 16, AIMovement.y[0], 32, 64);
Rectangle robot2 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[2] + 16, AIMovement.y[2], 32, 64);
Rectangle robot3 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[3] + 16, AIMovement.y[3], 32, 64);
Rectangle robot4 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[4] + 16, AIMovement.y[4], 32, 64);
```

In the code I first make a non-static way to refrence the class. After that I try to make the variables using the cords from the other classes. This is were it gives me the nullpointerexeption, right on the line of the first rectangle. All three of the classes I am using are created around the same time, this is the code:

```
Main Main;
Movement Movement;
AIMovement AIMovement;
Bullet Bullet;
entityCollision entityCollision;

public GamePanel() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
    Movement = new Movement();
    AIMovement = new AIMovement();
    Bullet = new Bullet();
    entityCollision = new entityCollision();
```

I get the error right after the code is created like in the code above.

I would like to know how would I make it were the entityCollision class is created after the other classes variables are not null or other ways of getting ride of the error.

Just comment and I will add more code or answer questions

Comment: What's the actual StackTrace?

Comment: Are you really using the same name `entityCollision` for both a variable and a class? I'm not sure if that'll even compile, but you don't want to do it. Every class name should start with an upper case letter. This is an important convention because it fixes ambiguity that arises eg because `.` has many different meanings in Java. FYI on terms, `new` creates an instance of a class, aka instantiates the class. It does not create the class or the code.

Comment: @Jerry101 It will allow the lowercase class name to compile, but it is, as you said, very bad practice.

Comment: General advice on debugging a NullPointerException: Step through the code in the debugger to see which line throws the exception and which values are null at that point.

Comment: @Jerrt101 I just renamed the class file to an uppercase e changed the variable to ec, but nothing changed

Comment: @jaredad7 a lowercase class name will compile but what about a variable name that's the same as a class name?

Comment: @Jerry101 Wow, I did not notice that. I guess java allows it, since it must compile to give him his exception. My only guess would be that it's okay as long as you don't have static variables in the class definition? I'm really surprised that java would let you do that.

Comment: @Typo How's your debugging going?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you go from

```
Rectangle robot1 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[0] + 16, AIMovement.y[0], 32, 64);
```

to

```
Rectangle robot2 = new Rectangle(AIMovement.x[2] + 16, AIMovement.y[2], 32, 64);?
```

On your fourth robot, if there is nothing in `AIMovement.x[4]` and/or the corresponding `y`, which I am assuming there is not, then you are passing a null pointer to the `Rectangle` class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First fix all the cases where you have a variable name that collides with a class name. The best way is to follow the convention of naming each variable starting with a lower case letter and each class starting with an upper case letter.

You have a bunch of these cases, and they make it ambiguous whether eg `Movement.x` gets the static variable `x` from the `Movement` class or the instance variable `x` from the `Movement` variable -- which is null so that expression will give a NullPointerException.

Now you need to set those variables before use.

If you're still puzzled on what's causing the exception, step through the code in the debugger and see where the exception happens and what's null at that point. You can split that statement into smaller parts if it has more than one expression that could cause the exception.

E.g. `new Rectangle(aIMovement.x[0] + 16, aIMovement.y[0], 32, 64)` will throw a NPE if `aIMovement` is null or `aIMovement.x` is null or `aIMovement.y` is null.